# How to translate "There is nothing more to talk about"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How can I translate the sentence "There is nothing more to talk about." into German? I have three sentences in mind:

> 1. Es gibt nichts mehr, über was zu reden.
> 2. Es gibt nichts mehr, worüber zu reden.
> 3. Es gibt nichts mehr, darüber zu reden.

I think only 1. should be correct, and 2.,3. are wrong. Is that right?

Comment: The subject is missing in all of your relative subclauses.

Comment: @Deve Right, so does that mean there's no construction in German like "There is nothing more to talk about" in English? In the English version, there is no subject after the "to". In German we can say "Es gibt nichts mehr zu sagen", but when there is a preposition ("about" in this case), must we completely change the structure?

Comment: I would simply translate with `Es gibt nichts mehr zu besprechen.` But what is the context?

Comment: As an informal, direct response to someone, "Da gibt es nichts mehr drüber zu reden." would sound more natural.

Comment: If it's to be used the way a "STFU!" would be, you could also use  "Ende der Diskussion!" as an option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a construction which is nearer to what you have suggested then you can use

> Es gibt nichts mehr, worüber zu reden wäre.

Otherwise choose one of the transitive verbs that the others have suggested, “bereden” or “besprechen”. Depending ob what meaning you want to convey, you could also say

> Es gibt nichts mehr zu diskutieren.

That one to me would indicate (depending on the context, of course), that you have decided and want no further discussion.

Comment: Thanks Carsten. Would you please elaborate on your first suggestion "Es gibt nichts mehr, worüber zu reden wäre"? Why is it okay to use "worüber zu reden wäre"? What kind of construction is this?

Comment: Or simply: `Es gibt nichts mehr zu reden.` Ganz einfach, kein Konjunktiv, oder sonstige Spielchen. Although using the latter was my first idea.

Comment: @MikaH.: That's subjunctive. Assuming there still would be something with the need to be talked over. But also to do this is not needed anymore. A way to stylistically express a quiet final decision.

Answer (score 5):

They all seem wrong to me. I would translate it as "Es gibt nichts mehr, worüber wir reden könnten.". Other solutions would be "Wir haben nichts mehr zu besprechen" or "Wir müssen über nichts mehr reden".

Comment: Example 1 here kind of says "you and I don't have anything to talk about any more".  It's correct, but I also interpret it as a dismissal.  your second example is correct.  #3 is more of a command of " we cannot talk about anything more".

Answer (score 2):

The most literal translation `Es gibt nichts mehr zu reden.` seems the most clear, honest way to express that there is nothing to talk about anymore.

Comment: In this case, we must be using "reden" as a **transitive** verb. Is that actually correct?

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt nichts mehr zu besprechen.

The examples provided kind of say "there isn't more about which to speak".  I understand it, but don't think that such a construction would be used.  Also, @Carsten S's "Es gibt nichts mehr to diskutieren" works well.  Besprechen is more to speak back and forth informally, diskutieren is more of a serious discussion.